# Rails 3.1.0 default_url_options for custom paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my routes.rb I have a custom path defined:

```
match "foo/copy" => "foo#copy", :via => [ :post ], :as => "copy_foo"
```

I have an initializer in my config/initializers directory named https_by_default.rb, which contains one line:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

If I run rails console and type `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options`, it returns `{:protocol => 'https}` as expected.

But in my view where I am using the generated custom path _url helper, it doesn't generate the URL with https. `<%= copy_foo_url() %>` in the ERB returns `http://localhost:3000/foo/copy`.

What am I missing in order to get my named routes helpers to respect default_url_options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following instead:

```
<%= copy_foo_path() %>
```

And in your application config file add.

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This enables ssl on all your Rails environments. If you want to enable ssl on your production environment only, then just add the line to your production config file.

Comment: Excellent! That seems to be working great. I'll have to test it further but this seems to do the trick. Thank you very much. I have some questions, though: this only forces SSL on our domain right? External links won't be coerced into HTTPS?

Comment: External links will automatically be redirected to use https by Rails.